# Compressing files with WinRar command-line - files in use

Tags: batch-file, command-line, zip, winrar

I am using this simple command to zip files into an archive with WinRar.

```
winrar a -afzip -ep1 "C:\ok.zip" "C:\ok"
```

But if something is running (for example a simple .exe) from that directory it gives me error:

> "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Is there any switch that would compress even the files in use.

I am sticking with WinRar as my customer has recommended it.

But would like your recommendations too, but don't think customer is going to let me use anything else.

Comment: Windows backup programs use Volume Shadow copy to copy locked files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`-DH`**, according to http://acritum.com/software/manuals/winrar/

I've not checked official manual, search for it.

Comment: thanks works perfectly, but can you also assist me on how to clear\delete files from the archive. i am using this command:
winrar a -afzip -ep1 -dh "C:\compi.zip" "C:\compi\"
It only updates the archive.